# Warning: Can't link and determine methods of class

Tags: java, selenium, ant

Java + Selenium + TestNG пытаюсь разобраться со сборкой антом, при сборке все ошибки победил, но при выполнении

> [testng] [TestNGClassFinder] Warning: Can't link and determine methods
>   of class newtechport.cases.NewTP_CheckElements
>
> [testng] [[TestNGClassFinder]] Unable to read methods on class newtechport.cases.NewTP_CheckElements - unable to resolve class
>   reference
>   org/apache/avalon/framework/configuration/ConfigurationException
>
> [testng] [TestNGClassFinder] Warning: Can't link and determine methods of class newtechport.cases.NewTP_CheckElements
>
> [testng] [TestNGClassFinder] Warning: Can't link and determine methods of class newtechport.cases.NewTP_CheckRegistrationOrder
>
> [testng] [[TestNGClassFinder]] Unable to read methods on class newtechport.cases.NewTP_CheckElements - unable to resolve class
>   reference
>   org/apache/avalon/framework/configuration/ConfigurationException
>
> [testng] [[TestNGClassFinder]] Unable to read methods on class newtechport.cases.NewTP_CheckRegistrationOrder - unable to resolve
>   class reference
>   org/apache/avalon/framework/configuration/ConfigurationException

Мой Build.xml:

```
<!--==================== Properties ========================== -->

<property name="src.dir" location="${basedir}\src" />
<property name="bin.dir" value="${basedir}\bin" />
<property name="lib.dir" location="${basedir}\lib" />
<property name="release.dir" value="${basedir}\release" />
<property name="xml.dir" value="${basedir}\projects\NewTP\test\" />
<property name="log.dir" value="${basedir}\projects\NewTP\log\" />
<property name="build.dir" value="${release.dir}\bin\" />
<property name="eclipse.lib.dir"
    value="${ECLIPSE_HOME}plugins\org.testng.eclipse_6.9.11.201604020423\lib\" />
<property name="TestNG.report.dir" value="${build.dir}\TestNGreport" />

<!--=================== Delete folders ======================== -->

<target name="delete">
    <delete dir="${release.dir}\projects\NewTP\log\" />
    <delete dir="${release.dir}\projects\NewTP\test\" />
    <delete dir="${release.dir}\projects\NewTP\" />
    <delete dir="${release.dir}\projects\" />
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${release.dir}\" />
    <delete dir="${release.dir}\src\" />
    <delete dir="${release.dir}\lib\" />
</target>


<!--================== Creating folders ======================= -->

<target name="create" description="Making of the auxillary dirs"
    depends="delete">
    <mkdir dir="${release.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${release.dir}\src\" />
    <mkdir dir="${release.dir}\lib\" />
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${release.dir}\projects\" />
    <mkdir dir="${release.dir}\projects\NewTP\" />
    <mkdir dir="${release.dir}\projects\NewTP\test\" />
    <mkdir dir="${release.dir}\projects\NewTP\log\" />
    <!--========================== Copy ============================= -->
    <copy todir="${release.dir}\projects\NewTP\test\">
        <fileset dir="${xml.dir}" includes="*.xml" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${release.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="*.properties" />
        <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="*.xml" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${release.dir}\src\">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.*" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${release.dir}\lib\">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/**.jar" />
    </copy>
</target>

<!--===================== Classpath ============================ -->

<path id="classpath">
    <pathelement path="${classpath}" />
    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}\selenium-java-2.53.0.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}\avalon-framework-4.1.4.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}\testng-6.8.7-sources.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}\testng-6.8.7.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${eclipse.lib.dir}testng.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${eclipse.lib.dir}jcommander.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${eclipse.lib.dir}bsh-2.0b4.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${eclipse.lib.dir}snakeyaml.jar" />
</path>

<!--=============== Compilation of the classes =================== -->

<target name="compile" description="Compilation of the classes"
    depends="create">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}"
        debug="off" classpathref="classpath">
    </javac>
</target>

<!--===================== TESTING ========================== -->
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpathref="classpath" />
<target name="CheckElements" description="Start tests" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${TestNG.report.dir}" />
    <testng outputdir="${TestNG.report.dir}">
        <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="testng.xml" />
        <classpath>
            <path id="classpath" />
            <pathelement location="${TestNG.report.dir}" />
            <pathelement location="${build.dir}" />
        </classpath>
        <classfileset dir="${build.dir}">
        </classfileset>         
    </testng>
</target>
```